# update data in slot vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

hi im using vuejs with laravel project 
and this is my vuejs code

```
Vue.component('search_and_select',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        '<slot :test_text="test_text"></slot>'+
    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            test_text:"test text",
        }
    },
    methods:{

    },
    props:{

    },
});
new Vue({
    el:'.user_search_and_select',
    data:{

    },
});
```

and this is my html code

```
<div is='search_and_select'>
    <div  slot-scope="{test_text}">
        @{{test_text}}
        <input type='text' v-model='test_text' />
    </div>
</div>
```

till now everything working so good 
but if i keyup `<input type='text' v-model='test_text' />` the `test_text` dont change still the same 
so how can i change in slot and change in parent component too 
thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to expose a method to the slot for updating the value. This means you won't be able to use `v-model` because you will need to handle `:value` and `@input` separately now.

```vue
<slot :test_text="test_text" :update_test_text="update_test_text"></slot>
```

```
methods: {
  update_test_text(value) {
    this.test_text = value
  }
}
```

Now you can use the component like this:

```vue
<search_and_select>
  <div slot-scope="{ test_text, update_test_text }">
    <input
      type="text"
      :value="test_text"
      @input="update_test_text($event.target.value)"
    >
  </div>
</search_and_select>
```